# Export a file in csv format programmatically with microsoft excel

Tags: excel, csv

I need to export a file in csv format programmatically.
I added the following function that I call when the user clicks on a button:

```
Public Sub CreateCVS()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="filename.csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

the problem is that I do not want to saveAs my file I want to export it in csv format but the spreadsheet should still be a xlsm file.

Is it possible

Answer (score 1):

Just export your worksheet first

```
Public Sub CreateCVS()
    activesheet.copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="filename.csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    activeworkbook.close false
End Sub
```